# Save generated code to .txt from batch

Tags: batch-file

So thanks to some help from this great site I was able to generate the specific code that I wanted but now I am trying to either name the generated code and/or save it to a txt file. I have played around with the destination with no luck. Im sure its something simple that I am missing. Thanks in advance. Seems like people here are very on the ball here. My last question was answered in less than 30 minutes :)

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem Define alphabet
set "alphabet=a b c d f g h i j k l m n p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

rem Create an "array" with the elements of the alphabet
set "size=0"
for %%a in (%alphabet%) do (
    set "a.!size!=%%a"
    set /a "size+=1"
)

rem Generate the output, selecting 32 randoms elements from the array
set "k="
for /l %%a in (1 1 32) do (
    set /a "r=!random! %% size"
    for %%b in (!r!) do set "k=!k!!a.%%b!"
)
echo(%k%

endlocal
%output%>C:\ME\Desktop\Gen.txt
```

Comment: Try redirecting the output when calling:  `name.bat > C:\ME\Desktop\Gen.txt`

Comment: No luck there. The code above generates my desired random code, But I do not know how to take the generated code and save it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two redirection symbols >>

One would simly overwrite so use two

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem Define alphabet
set "alphabet=a b c d f g h i j k l m n p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

rem Create an "array" with the elements of the alphabet
set "size=0"
for %%a in (%alphabet%) do (
    set "a.!size!=%%a"
    set /a "size+=1"
)

rem Generate the output, selecting 32 randoms elements from the array
set "k="
for /l %%a in (1 1 32) do (
    set /a "r=!random! %% size"
    for %%b in (!r!) do set "k=!k!!a.%%b!"
)

echo (!k!
echo(!k!>>"C:\ME\Desktop\Gen.txt"

Pause>null

endlocal
```

Also when you have delayed expansion enabled , you enclose variable references with the  use of ! Instead of %

Comment: ok ao this- (echo(!k!>>"C:\ME\Desktop\Gen.txt") copies the code to a txt file but now doesnt show in the cmd window- is there anyway to keep it in the window and still save to .txt? if not I can make this work.